# Hidding one li items when clicked on another li item

Tags: jquery

I used jquery toggle function to show hide the drop-down menu, but if one menu is opened and i try to open another one then previous one is not hiding anybody help me out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>");

    $("ul.topnav li span").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").toggle('medium');
    }).hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("subhover");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("subhover");
    });
});

<ul class="topnav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Geneology</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">Plan</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Leg View</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Smart Pin</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">My Pin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Send Pins</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pin History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Request Pin</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please make a fiddle demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your subnavs are initially hiden with some css 
(if not please let me know the initial state of your nav)
so try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>");

    $("ul.topnav li span").click(function() {
        var $this=$(this),
            $parent=$this.parent(),
            $shown=$('ul.topnav .shown').not($this.prev('.subnav')); //get the visible subnav but not the one I'm clicking

        //check if there are some subnav visible and hide it
        if($shown.size())
            $shown.hide('medium').removeClass('shown');

        $parent.find("ul.subnav").toggle('medium').toggleClass('shown');
    }).hover(function() { //I guess you are doing some hovering effect here
        $(this).addClass("subhover");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("subhover");
    });
});
```